# Linear transformation ker and image

Tags: matrices, transformation, linear-transformations

Let $\varphi\colon \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be described by $\varphi(X)=AX$ where 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $
. Find base vectors of $\ker \varphi$ and $\operatorname{Im} \varphi$.   In my opinion those vectors will be $[-1,1,0,0]$ and $[-1,0,1,0]$ for kernel and $[3,1,2]$  and  $[3,1,1] $ for image. Am I correct?

Comment: Neither of your candidate vectors for a basis of the kernel are actually in the kernel.

Comment: The image of A is 3 dimensional. It is linear combinations of the columns of A. Write down $A^T$ and do row reduction (Gaussian elimination) on the 4 rows. The none zero rows are a basis for the image of A.

Comment: This is a rank $3$ matrix (prove it) so your image should be $3$-dimensional (so why not use the obvious basis) and your kernel should be $1$-dimensional by the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Thus what should i do to find basis of the kernel?

Comment: @kurkowski Solve $AX=0$ for $X$.  user84413 already gave you the RREF, which reduces the problem to solving $RX=0$ for $X$ (because $2$ row equivalent matrices share the same kernel).  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I know how to solve RX=0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the definitions:
$$\ker\varphi:=\{X\in\mathbb R^4:\varphi(X)=0\},$$ that is, the set of all $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Can you find the solution set of this system? If so, you will be able to write down a basis for $\ker\varphi$. Note that row reducing yields
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so
\begin{align}
x_1-x_3&=0,\\
x_2+2x_3&=0,\\
x_4&=0
\end{align}
and thus
$x_4=0$, $x_2=-2x_3$, $x_1=x_3$ and $x_3$ is free. Hence a basis for $\ker\varphi$ is
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

As for $\text{Im}\,\varphi$, again go to the definition
$$
\text{Im}\,\varphi:=\{Y\in\mathbb{R}^3:\varphi(X)=Y\text{ for some }x\in\mathbb{R}^4\}.$$ So look at all possible outputs of $\varphi$ acting on an $X$ after row reducing:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Since you have leading ones in columns 1, 2, and 4, use columns 1, 2, and 4 of the original matrix as the basis for $\text{Im}\,\varphi$.

Comment: really appreciate your effort, thank you

Comment: @kurkowski: then you should give JohnD an upvote :-)

Comment: @Bye_World: Typo, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Reducing your matrix to RREF gives $\;$ $R=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&0\\0&1&2&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$;

Now solve $Rx=0$ to get a basis for the kernel, and

take the columns in A corresponding to the leading 1's in R to get a basis for the image.

Comment: thus basis of the image will be $[3,1,2],[3,1,1],[2,1,1]$ and basis of the kernel will be $[1,2,1,0]$?

Comment: @kurkowski the $2$ in the basis vector of the kernel should be $-2$.  Otherwise, yep.  That's correct (though an easier basis for the image to work with -- if you plan on using these basis vectors for anything -- is $[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]$).

Comment: you're right, thank you